# nullity and rank

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea what the question is asking

1. If A is row equivalent to $\mathbf I_5$, then the nullity of A is
2. If T: $\mathbf M_n\times n (\Bbb R) \rightarrow \mathbf M _n\times n (\Bbb R)$ is an isomorphism, then the rank(T)=

(sorry about the typing, I do not know how to make $n\times n$ as a lower subscript)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 0):

1. NullSpace is built-in for this part of the questions.
   5 is the unity matrix of the five-dimensional space. The nullity is therefore {}.
   5 is the unit vector of the fifth component in five-dimensional space then the nullity is

   NullSpace[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}]

`{{0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`}

the four-dimensional subspace of the five-dimensional space not including the fifth component.

Equivalent implies that the vector `A` is in the span of `5`.

2. In mathematics, an isomorphism is a mapping between two structures, here ×(ℝ), of the same type that can be reversed by an inverse mapping. In this case a matrix ×(ℝ) name T. For the inversion it is needed that the rank(T)=n otherwise the nullity would not be `{}` anymore.

Mathematica has the built-in MatrixRank that is not needed to put to operation for the answer.